# How to use locator in evaluate's javascript in Playwright python

Tags: javascript, python, playwright, playwright-python

I have the following script running:

```py
def test_combobox_selected_by_label(page):
    page.goto("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php")
    element = page.get_by_role("combobox")
    element.select_option("Colorado -- CO")
    selected_label = page_custom.evaluate("document.getElementsByName('selectionField')[0].options[document.getElementsByName('selectionField')[0].selectedIndex].text")
    assert selected_label == "Colorado -- CO"
```

I"m using javascript for element, to extract the selected option's label text.

How could I reformat the element variable to use the previously defined locator (`get_by_role("combobox")`) from select_elem?

In short, how can I use the locator variable (select_elem) **in evaluate's javascript**?

Locators should be:

```py
page.get_by_role("combobox")
```

or

```py
page.locator("[name=selectionField]").first
```

Note: you may run the above script, this is a live page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for `element.evaluate()`:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php")
    element = page.get_by_role("combobox")
    element.select_option("Colorado -- CO")
    text = element.evaluate("el => el.options[el.selectedIndex].text")
    assert text == "Colorado -- CO"
```